# Should I use a category or a custom helper class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

My goal is to be able to create a unique string based on a timestamp and some other information. I will be doing this many times through-out the code base, so code reuse and maintainability implies that I should make one spot to do this.

Since this unique ID will always be stored into an NSString, I could make a category on NSString that will create this unique id...

```
NSString *uniqueString = [NSString stringWithTimestamp:timestamp andName:name];
```

Or I could create a custom helper class with a class method to return a unique string string...

```
NSString *uniqueString = [HelperClass stringWithTimestamp:timestamp andName:name];
```

Wouldn't creating the helper class typically be better because I can import it into other projects and use that method, as well as other unrelated methods I may have created (easily contained all in one file)?  If I used categories, they'd be spread out in a bunch of different files.

But this can't be right, because with this logic there would rarely be a need for categories, and just always create a helper class for a project with these helper methods in it...I must be missing something!

Comment: I don't see the logic for making it a category method on `NSString`. Just because it returns a string doesn't mean it has anything to do with the `NSString` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest the helper class approach since the unique id method has no relation to NSString class other than the return type. Just imagine, in future if you plan to create an NSInteger as unique id then this method wont have any relation to NSString class. So a helper class is the right approach here.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, this is a matter of personal preference: you pick what you think would provide you with better readability, because the performance and maintainability would be the same.

Another choice is to create a category on `NSDate`, so you can call it the way you call an instance method (as opposed to calling a class method):

```
NSString *uniqueString = [timestamp uniqueStringWithName:name];
```

Comment: Assuming `timestamp` is an `NSDate`, this approach makes far more sense than making it a class category method on `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say helper class is better for multiple helper methods as you say across multiple classes, while a category works well when the class you are extending will be overwritten and you want to preserve your extensions, i.e. in case of NSManagedObject subclasses generated from core data model, or classes you will be updating in a subproject managed with CocoaPods.